# Dates within a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a scenario where we have various orders that get completed with a start and end time. I am trying to only get records within a certain time frame and calculate the duration in seconds. For the sake of argument, lets say 24 hours. I need to use the orders below and see which orders call within the range and only calculate the duration between each order that fall within the 24 hour time frame/ date range. Anything outside the time frame for each order do not contribute towards the duration for each order. I have data very similar to below.

```
Order #         Start                           End
Order 1         2018-09-20 11:00.00.000         2018-09-21 09:00.00.000
Order 2         2018-09-20 10:30.00.000         2018-09-21 08:00.00.000
Order 3         2018-09-20 10:21.00.000         2018-09-20 18:00.00.000
Order 4         2018-09-20 11:50.00.000         2018-09-21 10:00.00.000
Order 5         2018-09-20 19:00.00.000         2018-09-21 02:00.00.000
```

Lets say I am trying to get the last 24 hours so the range would be

`2018-09-20 11:00.00.000 to 2018-09-21 11:00.00.000`

Comment: And the expected result is ? And with explanation and / or formula on any calculation on the result

Comment: And your code so far is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following diagram attempts to explain logic for selecting data by a date/time range:

```
Period Start "Ps"
Period End "Pe"

    Ps       Pe
s-E |        |        ignore, starts & ends before the period (E not > Ps)

 s--|--------|-E      spans the period
  s-|---E    |        start before, but ends in, the period
    s----E   |        starts at beginning of the period, finishes before the period ends
    | s---E  |        starts and finished within the period
    |   s----E        starts within the period, finishes on last day of the period
    |     s--|-E      starts within the period but finishes after the period

    |        | s-E    ignore, starts & ends after the period (s not < Pe)

     s < Pe
   + E >= Ps
```

Using that logic the query might be:

```
DECLARE @Ps AS datetime = '2018-09-20 11:00.00.000'
DECLARE @Pe AS datetime = DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @Ps)

SELECT
    t.*
FROM yourtable AS t
WHERE t.[start] < @Pe
AND t.[end] >= @Ps
```

It may seem counter-intuitive but compare the order start to the period end, and vice-versa, the order end to the period start.